# Adobe Animate alternative ClickToGoToWebPage

Tags: javascript, animation, html5-canvas, adobe

I've created an intro in Adobe Animate CC 2017 as default page for my website.
On the end of the intro, 2 buttons are appearing to chose the desired language.

I can do that with the code snippet ClickToGoToWebPage select _parent, no problem in that. But what i really want, is, when you click the button, the elements will fade out one by one (already did that) and then go that page when all the elements are faded out (so the last frame).

I've been looking all over the Net and can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

When you add the ClickToGoToWebPage code-snippet, simply replace the code inside the handler function to trigger fade out animation. and at the last frame of your fading symbol, place the code that was originally placed in the handler function.

Eg: Set up the fade-out animation on the button, nested within a symbol.
On the first frame of this symbol, write -

```
    this.stop();
    this.on("click", function (){this.play();});
```

On the last frame of this symbol, write -

```
    this.stop();
    window.open("http://www.adobe.com", "_blank");
```